# cycle through array of records in react-final-form

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-final-form

I have a form in a component that will have a few records to cycle through.  the records are called and stored in the redux store on componentdidMount. I am having trouble "cycling" through the records on my form. I can set initial values easily enough but what is the best approach when the user clicks next to have react-final-form re initialize with the data from the next record in the collection (data[x])?

```
    export type IFormDataStatProps = {
    data: Array<FormData>;
}

export interface IFormDataDispatchProps {
    getData: () => void;
}

type IFormDataPageProps = IFormDataStatProps & IFormDataDispatchProps;

class FormPage extends React.Component<IFormDataPageProps> {

    constructor(props: IFormDataPageProps) {
        super(props);
    }

    public componenetDidMount() {
        this.props.getData();
    }

    onSubmit = (values) => {
        window.alerty(JSON.stringify(values, undefined, 2));
    }

    nextRecord = () => {
        //something here to reinitialize the form with data from next array position (data[1]).  There might be something built into react-final-form to do this.
    }

    public render() {
        return (
            <Form
                onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
                initialVaues={{
                    firstName: data[0].firstName,
                    lastName: data[0].lastName
                }}
                render={({ handleSubmit, form, submitting, pristine, values}) => (
                    <Field
                        name="firstName"
                        component="input"
                    />

                    <Field
                        name="lastName"
                        component="input"
                    />

                    <button type="submit">Save</button>
                    <button onClick={this.nextRecord}>Next</button>
                )}
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: a [mcve] would help

Comment: I added a code block for example.